# how to group_concat using distinct correctly - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, filter, distinct, group-concat

I have 3 table relation using **MYSQL**;

Example first as riders table:

```
bib   |   series_id    | point
 202         3             200
 219         3             140
 202         2             200
 219         2             110
 10          1             90
```

Example second as series table:

```
series_id   |   series_no  |   season_id
     1            1                2
     2            2                1
     3            1                1
```

Example third as seasons table:

```
 season_id   |   year
     1            2015
     2            2016
```

How to `GROUP_CONCAT` point correctly? I'm trying like this

```
SELECT riders.bib, seasons.year, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT riders.point ORDER BY series.series_no DESC) AS seriPoint 
    FROM series, riders, seasons 
    GROUP BY riders.bib
```

I'm getting output seriPoint for `bib: 202 is 200 and bib: 219 is 140,110` when I'm using `DISTINCT` output like that. But when I'm not using `DISTINCT` getting output seriPoint for `bib: 202 is 200,200,200,200 and bib: 219 is 140,110,140,110`. What I want is output seriPoint for `bib: 202 is 200,200 and bib: 219 is 140,110`.

**ADD:** please help to add filter too, for `season_id` when different `season_id` its to be different row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you are getting correct output since you have used `DISTINCT`. BTW, you should change your query to use proper JOINS

```
SELECT riders.bib, 
seasons.year, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT riders.point ORDER BY series.series_no DESC) AS seriPoint 
FROM riders
JOIN series ON series.series_id = riders.series_id
JOIN seasons ON series.season_id = seasons.season_id
GROUP BY riders.bib;
```

(OR) you can get the grouping first and then perform join like

```
select seasons.year, xx.bib, xx.seriPoint
FROM series
JOIN (  
select series_id, bib 
group_concat(point) as seriPoint 
from riders
group by bib ) xx ON series.series_id = xx.series_id
JOIN seasons ON series.season_id = seasons.season_id
order by xx.seriPoint;
```

Comment: I want ask more. How to `ORDER BY ` sum my `seriPoint`. 200,200 = 400. Thank @Rahul

Comment: @Stfvns, you can add a `order by` clause. See edit in answer (2nd query) if that helps.